# capistrano fails on assets:precompile within cap deploy:cold

Tags: capistrano

I am doing a cap deploy:cold

with the following config/deploy.rb

```
1 require 'bundler/capistrano'
  2 
  3 set :application, "massiveapp"
  4 
  5 set :scm, :git
  6 
  7 set :repository, "git://github.com/deployingrails/massiveapp.git"
  8 
  9 server "localhost", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
 10 
 11 ssh_options[:port] = 2222
 12 ssh_options[:keys] = "~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
 13 
 14 set :user, "vagrant"
 15 set :group, "vagrant"
 16 set :deploy_to, "/var/massiveapp"
 17 set :use_sudo, false
 18 
 19 set :deploy_via, :copy
 20 set :copy_strategy, :export
 21 
 22 namespace :deploy do
 23   task :start do ; end
 24   task :stop do ; end
 25   desc "Restart the application"
 26   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
 27     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 28   end
 29   desc "Copy the database.yml file into the latest release"
 30   task :copy_in_database_yml do
 31     run "cp #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/"
 32   end
 33 end
 34 #before "deploy:copy_in_database_yml"
 35 before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:copy_in_database_yml"
```

It all goes fine up to the following at which point it fails.

```
* executing "cd /var/massiveapp/releases/20120808053801 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["localhost"]
    [localhost] executing command
*** [err :: localhost] rake aborted!
*** [err :: localhost] (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1
*** [err :: localhost] 
*** [err :: localhost] Tasks: TOP => environment
*** [err :: localhost] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 1196ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/massiveapp/releases/20120808053801; true"
    servers: ["localhost"]
    [localhost] executing command
    command finished in 39ms
```

I am just learning capistrano and just don't know how to debug this to solve it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

rails 3.2.7 ruby 1.9.3 capistrano 2.12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was caused by a tab character in the database.yml file.

Answer (score 2):

The database.yml file is on the VM located at `/var/massiveapp/shared/configs/database.yml`.